# Display all data from db before search

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to build a page which displays all data from db before search and after search it should display only the results of the search.

So far I've been able to display the data after search..

I'm trying to display it before search.... that is.. I have to display the data once before the search even begun i.e., when the page loads

I'm able to display the search results and I'm able to display all the data in db only when any key is pressed..

I should be able to view all the data in db at the time when the page loads.

I've tried the below code but it doesn't work...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search_text').keyup(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    console.log(txt);
    if (txt == '') {
      console.log("Enter text");
      $('#result').html('');
      $.ajax({
        url: "fetch_data.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {search: txt},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("Data = "+data);
          $('#result').html(data);
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      $('#result').html('');
      $.ajax({
        url: "fetch_data.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {search: txt},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("Data = "+data);
          $('#result').html(data);
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

And my *fetch_data.php* is:

```
<?php

    include_once "class.php";

    $class = new Class();


    if($_POST["search"] == '') {
        // echo "Empty";
        $class->list();
    }
    else {
        $search_data = $_POST["search"];        

        $class->search($search_data);
    }

?>
```

Help please...

Comment: are you returning the results from list and search functions or atleast echo them?

Comment: If the search box is empty all data will be displayed.. That is the use of list(). If the search box is not empty the search results will be displayed

Comment: Not really an answer, but looking at the code, I don't think the `if/else` is even needed in the script, because you can instead check the content of `txt` in `fetch_data.php` like what you are doing now

Comment: Are you getting any erorr?

Comment: is `$class->search($data);` echoing something?

Comment: No i dont get  an error

Comment: The search function will echo the search results

Comment: @Lublaut this can be relevant to see the `search` method

Comment: I dont understand @Cid

Comment: Would you show us the code you've typed for the `search()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!!

I changed my *js* file as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="search_text"]').on('keyup', function() {

          var input, filter, tr, td, i;

          input  = $(this);
          filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
          tr     = $("table tr");

          for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
              td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
              if (td) {
                  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                      tr[i].style.display = "";
                  } else {
                      tr[i].style.display = "none";
                  }
              }
          }
      })
})
```

and my *fetch_data.php* has only:

```
<?php           
    $class = new Class();
    $class->list();         
?>
```

It works now..